# C# Excel создание выпадающего списка в ячейке

Tags: c#

Вывожу в Excel данные в C# WinForms. В одной ячейке мне нужно, чтобы был выпадающий список с вариантами (при этом одно из значений было бы выбрано).

Использую

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
ExcelApp.Columns.ColumnWidth = 15;

ExcelApp.Cells[1, 1] = "Текст";

ExcelApp.Visible = true;
```

Тут я просто текст поместил в ячейку, а как сделать выпадающий список нигде не нашел. Так же, как отметить выбранное значение, чтобы оно было сохранено.
[image: пример того, что хочу получить]

Comment: Посмотрите этот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19714888/4924596

Answer (score 0):

```
var excel = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
var worksheet = (Worksheet)excel.ActiveSheet;

var list = new List<string>();
list.Add("Текст1");
list.Add("Текст2");
list.Add("Текст3");

var flatList = string.Join(",", list.ToArray());

var cell = (Range)worksheet.Cells[2, 2];
cell.Validation.Delete();
cell.Validation.Add(
   XlDVType.xlValidateList,
   XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertInformation,
   XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween,
   flatList,
   Type.Missing);

cell.Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;
cell.Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
```